# CloudWatch Alarm Using `DATAPOINT_COUNT`

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I have a metric `SomeMetric` with three dimensions: `Arn`, `Source`, `Name`. I want an alarm that fires whenever in the last 5 minutes, there've been at least 3 datapoint with unique `Arn`.

I'm using CloudFormation to create the alarms, so I wrote something like this

```yaml
SomeAlarm:
  Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
  Properties:
      AlarmName: SomeAlarm
      AlarmDescription: ...
      ActionsEnabled: true
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      DatapointsToAlarm: 1
      Threshold: 3
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
      TreatMissingData: notBreaching
      Metrics:
          - Id: e1
            Label: Expression1
            ReturnData: true
            Expression: DATAPOINT_COUNT(q1)
          - Id: q1
            Label: Query1
            ReturnData: false
            Expression: >-
                SELECT COUNT(SomeMetric) FROM
                                  SCHEMA(MyNamespace, Arn, Source, Name)
                                  GROUP BY Arn
            Period: 300
```

However, reading about `DATAPOINT_COUNT` in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html
It says that

> We recommend that you do not use this function in CloudWatch alarms.
> Whenever an alarm evaluates whether to change state, CloudWatch
> attempts to retrieve a higher number of data points than the number
> specified as Evaluation Periods. This function acts differently when
> extra data is requested.

If I'm not supposed to use that inside alarms, is there any alternative I can use to achieve the same thing?